# Fix 'Unable to display current owner' on file permissions programatically

Tags: c#, .net, acl

We have some files that people 'move' from one server where only they have permissions to another server where many people have permissions, when they cut and paste instead of copy and paste it takes across the permissions.

I am trying to remedy this, as it causes a lot of problems when non-administrators are trying to do anything with these files, I can do it manually by the following long-winded method (once per file moved in this manner):

Until i do this, `File.GetAccessControl("x:\filename")` throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, so i don't see how i can change the permissions if i can't even retrieve them in the first place..

Is there any way to automate the tedious steps seen in the screenshots below?

[image]

Comment: Sure you can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to set the ownership, but i can't even retrieve the security settings object to set it - it fails on `File.GetAccessControl("x:\filename")` (it says this in my question)

Comment: Is it possible for you to run the application as administrator?

Comment: I am running it as admin, I have managed to get it working now but only by being added to the Domain Admins AD group (which has full control on everything) - not sure why I can change the permissions manually via the method above on individual items, but can't set it on the parent folder or manage it via code.